# extending c++ math functions to non fundamental types

Tags: c++, math, overloading

I want to extend? or overload?(not too sure what to call it) the sqrt() function used by double and other fundamental types so the it can be used by my own class. Here called "myType". I will code the function sqrt() for when its  argument is a myType. I want sqrt() to stay intact when it is used for the fundamental types. So that I can write one template that covers both cases.

For example. The key thing for below is to be able to use bar() for both fundamental and myType. Not foo() for myType and bar() for the fundamental types. Can this be done cleanly? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class myType
{
public:
    myType() {
    }
    double sqrt()
    {
        return  4;//just to return something
    }
};

template<typename T> bool bar(T in)
{
    if (sqrt(in) == 4) {// handels int and all sorts of other types but not my type
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T> bool foo(T in)
{
    if (in.sqrt() == 4) { //handles myType
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    double y = 3;
    bar(y);//This is great

    myType x;
    //bar(x);//this is the line I want to write
    foo(x);//stuck doing this
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is argument-dependent lookup (ADL, a.k.a. König Lookup) which searches for the function `foo()` in the namespace of its argument. So, if you define your class in namespace `my`, you can define a function `sqrt()` in that namespace and it will automatically be found even if called in an unqualified context.

Secondly, in order to make your template functions generic, you need to enable ADL. However, it still won't look inside namespace `std` if you use this with fundamental types. Therefore, give the compiler a hint that `std::sqrt` may be used in the function.

Example (sketch):

```
namespace my {
    struct number;
    number sqrt(number const&);
}

template<typename scalar>
scalar
sym_sqrt(scalar const& s) {
    using std::sqrt;
    if (s < 0) {
        return -sqrt(-s);
    else
        return sqrt(s);
}

int main() {
    float m = ...;
    std::cout << sym_sqrt(m);

    my::number n = ...;
    std::cout << sym_sqrt(n);
}
```

#### Notes

- I did not `using namespace std;`. This should neither be necessary and in particular not be required by the users of your class. Get rid of this habit now!
- Concerning the wording, you can't extend a function, but you add overloads to the existing overloads.
- If you use an ancient compiler, you might have issues with `sqrt` being a macro. Just upgrade the compiler then.
- Note that `sqrt()` in your attempt is defined as a member function, which is a whole different beast. Keep it as free function similar to the existing versions. In general, don't blindly put things into classes. There are good reasons to use plain functions. In particular the math functions that represent functions in the mathematical sense (no side-effects, no external dependencies) are actually well placed into functions.
- `std::sqrt()` is already overloaded for non-fundamental types, namely for the different `std::complex<T>` types.
- `if (X) {return true;} else {return false};` can be written much smaller as `return X;`.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked the edits. @Toby, I did not realize your edits were such a big part of the answer. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do anything to make `std::sqrt` work with your user-defined types (unless they can be converted to a basic data type using a conversion operator). But you could write your own function that redirects to `std::sqrt` by default, and specialize it for your user-defined types. Then use that function in your code instead of `std::sqrt`.